# Jquery - Mostrar Librería de Imágenes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, modal

mediante una ventana modal muestro una librería de imágenes por cliente. Utilizo el siguiente código HTML combinado con PHP:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="selectImagesProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change" aria-hidden="true">

          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

               <div class="modal-content">

                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Selecciona Imatges</h3>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="">
                            <?php
                              $directory="prod/images/cliente1";
                              $dirint = dir($directory);
                              while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
                              {
                                  if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo) || substr($archivo, 1, 1) != '.'){
                                      echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'" width="50">'."\n";
                                  }
                              }
                              $dirint->close();
                            ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-footer " >
                          <div class="pull-right">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesAdd' value="Afegir">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesSelect' value="Seleccionar">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesFinalitzar' style="background-color: #404040; color: white;" value="Finalitzar">
                          </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Con este código me muestra de la siguinte manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo cuando una librería es demasiado grande por ejemplo la de un cliente con 6000 referencias, tarda muchísimo en cargar y me devuelve un error de ERR_INSUFICIENT_RESOURCES

La finalidad de la librería es poder buscar imágenes y agregarlas a la ficha del producto, para ello, necesito un textbox realizando funciones de buscador y una paginación. Es decir, no me vale ir cargando los productos por número limitado y por página, los necesito todos para poder buscarlos si es necesario.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda al respecto.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122506/neterr-insufficient-resources-error-when-adding-numerous-img-elements-to-dom
se encuentran con el mismo problema y alguno sugiere paginación, otro scroll infinito, y uno algo original, usar Isotope, una forma de organizar imágenes muy visual:

https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Pero no creo que solucione tu problema, ya que la carga se realiza igualmente en la parte de cliente, pues no hay otra forma, además se comenta que parece ser un bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108055 y proporcionan workarounds para solucionarlo aunque no los he probado.

Comment: Gracias por la info, voy a leerlo con atención.